# Spark: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am getting following exception trace and not able to identify its root cause:

```
WARN HttpChannel: //ip-10-0-1-137.ec2.internal:4040/api/v1/applications/application_1565230812086_0001/allexecutors?proxyapproved=true
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 53
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 53
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.apply(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:65)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.apply(Stream.scala:202)
    ...
```

[full stacktrace link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DTOlBa-uGm1cIJZRniDwMRKf1b5DQkK3FXyELer1YkE/edit?usp=sharing)

Though this is not terminating execution, but still want to know its cause. Can this lead to low performance of spark machines?

Version:

```
Scala: 2.11
Spark: 2.2.1
```

Comment: when exactly does this happen

Comment: I am still not sure about its place. I have a list of spark sql and running them sequentially. The first dataframe, which I am persisting, throws this warning.

Comment: Can u add some of the code also so we can see what else is going on

Comment: I will not be able to add code as I am not owner of it. Sample code is not giving me this warning. Also in fresh EMR cluster I am not getting this warning. Looks to me intermittent issue.